# Fill color to pointer in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm using scatter graph. On hover over a point, the box representing the point color is not filled

[image: Look here]

I need to fill it with the color of the line instead of just the border being of the color.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imMak/y1qn82mx/14)

This is my dataset:

```
this.ScatterChart.data.datasets.push({
  label: this.label,
  data: this.Axiscoordinates,
  fill: false,
  lineTension: 0.1,
  borderColor: SetColor,
  color: SetColor,
  backGroundColor: SetColor,
  borderWidth: 1,
  yAxisID: this.yAxisUnit,
  showLine: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your dataset object put the backgroundColor to the color you want it to be, that will solve it

```
datasets: [
  {
    data: []
    backgroundColor: color
  }
]
```

EDIT:My mistake backgroundColor is with a lower g instead of a captial one

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Tried that but does not work. Have added my dataset to the question if you'd like to have a look :)

Comment: Can you provide all of your code because when I test it, it seems to work just fine, example: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/3nre61kp/8/

Comment: It looks similar but doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/imMak/y1qn82mx/14/

Comment: Found the issue, backgroundColor is not with a capital G, my mistake